# Following SQL generates error 1005 and errno 150 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

The following SQL causes mysql to generate error 1005, and errno 150 in message:

```
CREATE TABLE Review_Record (
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE ,
  file MEDIUMBLOB,
  submission_id INT not null ,
  reviewer_id VARCHAR(50) not null ,
  file_mime VARCHAR(20),
  rating INT,
  assigned_time TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  completed_time TIMESTAMP,
  completed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE ,
  FOREIGN KEY (submission_id) REFERENCES Submission (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (reviewer_id) REFERENCES Reviewer (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

After looking up the mysql docs, I find the following description about this error:

> - 1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)
>
> Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table
>   creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly
>   formed. If the error message refers to error −1, table creation
>   probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched
>   the name of an internal InnoDB table.

But how is my foreign key constraint incorrectly formed?

Comment: Do you have the same data type for submission_id and reviewer_id as the referenced columns?  (reviewer_id being varchar 50 makes me wonder)

Comment: Oh stupid me! Used `varchar` on a `int` key! Thanks @Devon !

Comment: You're welcome.  Problem solved?

Comment: Yes! You can post an answer below and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating foreign keys, it is important to make sure that the data types and character sets are the same.

In this case, the data type of `Reviewer.id` (int) did not match `Review_Record.reviewer_id` (varchar 50).

(Refer to comments)